# Google Analytics Events not showing up in Debug View reliably

Tags: google-analytics

I am having trouble ensuring my GA events are being reported correctly.  To try to debug the issue, I created a page with a button that sends a `sign_up` event every time I press the button, along with a random number to the `method` property just so I have some way of correlating my button presses to events.  I output the random number used to the console on each button press.

Now I go into the Dashboard and view "Debug View".  Events show up there sometimes.  Sometimes I have to select a specific "Debug Device", sometimes I don't.  I can see events being added to the "Debug View" history WELL into the past - like an event might be added to the history 20 minutes after it was fired.  It will show up in the history in the right spot, but I was under the impression the "Debug View" was supposed to be pretty realtime.

Some events never show up at all.

I have turned off all "Data Filters".  I can see the event is being sent in the Network Tab of Chrome.

Why are the events not reliably showing up in the Debug View?  If I click the button 20 times I maybe get 5 events showing up in roughly real-time, 5 events added to the Debug View history after the fact (with a delay of up to 20 minutes or more), and 10 events just never show up at all.

For the specifics, in this case I'm using `react-ga4`.  The code to initialize GA is as such (in `App.tsx`):

```
  ReactGA.initialize([
    {
      trackingId: process.env.REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_ID,
      gaOptions: {
        debug_mode: !!process.env.REACT_APP_GA_DEBUG,
        send_page_view: false,
      },
      gtagOptions: {
        debug_mode: !!process.env.REACT_APP_GA_DEBUG,
      },
    },
  ]);
```

The code triggered by the button press is as such (I know this code is being correctly executed because I can see the console output and the network tab):

```
  const randomNumber = _.random(1000, false);
  console.log('Tracking ID: ' + process.env.REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING_ID);
  console.log('GA DEBUG MODE: ' + process.env.REACT_APP_GA_DEBUG);
  console.log('Random Number: ' + randomNumber);
  ReactGA.event('sign_up', { method: String(randomNumber) });
```